# Dynamically add wtforms fields in table using javascript and send back to view

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I need to dynamically add a number of fiedlists in flask-wtforms and then send it back to a database. The idea is that the user adds his details and then can add a number of rows. I'm able to add the rows in a table using jquery but I'm pretty lost on how to actually send that back my view and into the database. It works for one row but when with more rows it just deletes the other rows and keeps the first row with the data in it. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQxk4.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1zom.png)

**forms.py**

```
class subProdData(FlaskForm):
      itemnmbr = StringField('Item number/Job Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
      jobStart = TimeField('Job Start time', validators=[DataRequired()])
      jobEnd = TimeField('Job End Time', validators=[DataRequired()])
      qty = IntegerField('Qty', validators=[DataRequired()])
      employee = IntegerField('Employees Id Number', validators=[DataRequired()])



class prodData1(FlaskForm):
     date = DateField('Date', format='%Y-%m-%d', validators=[DataRequired()])
     department = SelectField('Department:', validators=[DataRequired()])
     shift = SelectField('Shift:', choices=[(1), (2)], validators=[DataRequired()])
     supervisor = SelectField('Supervisor', validators=[DataRequired()])
     employeesNum = IntegerField('# of employees:')
     notes = TextAreaField('Notes:', validators=[Length(min=0, max=140)])
     jobInfo = FieldList(FormField(subProdData), min_entries=1)
     submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**addForm.html**

```
<form method="POST">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
<div class="container">
<div class="content-section">
<h1>Add Data Report</h1>
    <br/>
  <div class="form-group required" id="supervisor"><label class="control-label">{{form.supervisor.label}}
      {{ form.supervisor(class_='form-control')}}</div>
  <div class="form-group required" id="shift"><label class="control-label">{{form.shift.label}}
      {{ form.shift(class_='form-control')}}</div>
  <div class="form-group required" id="date"><label class="control-label">{{form.date.label}}
      {{ form.date(class_='form-control')}}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="formdepartment" id="shift"><label class="control-label">{{form.department.label}}
      {{ form.department(class_='form-control')}}</div>
  <div class="formdepartment" id="employee"><label class="control-label">{{form.employeesNum.label}}
      {{ form.employeesNum(class_='form-control')}}</div>

  <div class="Notes">
    <div class="formnotes" id="notes"><label class="control-label">{{form.notes.label}}
        {{ form.notes(class_='form-control')}}</div>
  </div>

<div data-toggle="fieldset" id="job-fieldset" class="form-group">
  <table class="ui table" id="tab1">
    <thead>
      <th>Item #/Job Description</th>
      <th>Job Start Time</th>
      <th>Job End Time</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Employees ID Number</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for e in form.jobInfo %}
      <tr data-toggle="fieldset-entry">
        <td>{{ e.itemnmbr(class_='form-control') }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.jobStart(class_='form-control') }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.jobEnd(class_='form-control') }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.qty(class_='form-control') }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.employee(class_='form-control') }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</div>
{{form.submit}}


<input type="button" value="add entry" id="add">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(e){
event.preventDefault()
$('#tab1').append('{% for e in form.jobInfo %}<tr data-toggle="fieldset-entry"><td> 
{{e.itemnmbr(class_='form-control')}}</td><td>{{e.jobStart(class_='form-control')}}</td><td> 
{{e.jobEnd(class_='form-control')}}</td><td>{{e.qty(class_='form-control')}}</td><td> 
{{e.employee(class_='form-control')}}</td>{% endfor %}');
});



});


</script>


{% endblock %}
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('/prodData/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def addProd():

form = prodData1(depData=current_user.username)

if form.validate_on_submit():
    data1 = (str(form.date.data), str(form.department.data), int(form.shift.data), str(form.supervisor.data), int(form.employeesNum.data),  int(form.employee.data), str(form.itemnmbr.data), str(form.jobStart.data), str(form.jobEnd.data), int(form.qty.data), str(form.notes.data) )
    try:
        sendProdData1(*data1)
        flash('Submitted')
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        flash('error')
    return redirect(url_for('prodData'))
return render_template('addProd1.html', form=form)
```

**sendToDB.py**

```
def sendProdData1(*args):
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor2.execute(
"""INSERT INTO [dbo].[prodInput](input_date, department, shift, supervisor, number_of_employees, employee_id, item_number, job_start, job_end, produced_qty, notes)
   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", args )
```

Comment: Can you please share what you ended up doing?

Comment: @Ashish I ended up abandoning jinja2 and used Vue.js instead, but still flask on the backend. It was easier in Vue.js and used Element UI. Their form component let me dynamically add form objects and sent it to the backend as one big object. From there I just parsed it and sent it to the DB. Let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just writing a little javascript to concatenate the fields into a single hidden field and sending the one field back to the server.